# c cannot be resolved to variable - java

Tags: java, variables

I have problems with this java code:

```
for(Clause c : clauses)
  {
  if(c.s == 0)
  {
    switch(c.formula.type)
    {

    //LITERAL
    case 0:

      {
          ArrayList<Clause> clauses_without_c = ((ArrayList<Clause>) clauses.clone());
          clauses_without_c.remove(c);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And i got error "c cannot be resolved to variable" in line:

```
clauses_without_c.remove(c);
```

What's the problem?

Comment: There is no syntax error that I can see in that code snippet.  Perhaps it is caused by something in the snippet's context?  Perhaps that is not the code that you are actually compiling?  What version of Java / what compiler are you using?

Comment: public ArrayList<Clause> clauses;

Comment: Is that really your code? it compiles fine for me. (java 1.6.0_22). Do you import the ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that clone() isn't doing what you think it is.

If clauses is an ArrayList, you should be reading the javadocs:

> Returns a shallow copy of this
>   ArrayList instance.

You should create a new container instance and deep copy all the values into it.

Comment: but the problems isn't with the cloned instance - it's the problem with c variable, that comes from the for each statement.